# Number of sequential values that starts from first position

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to know which and how many sequential color from the top of the stack but only for that starts in position 1  from the top :

color   position 
           in stack

```
+   red   +  1
|   red   |  2
|   red   |  3     
|   blue  |  4     Stack A
|   blue  |  5
|   red   |  6
|   red   |  7 
+---------+      


|   red   |  1     Stack B  
+---------+     
|   blue  |  1
|   red   |  2
|   red   |  3     Stack C
|   blue  |  4
+---------+
```

The table :

```
Stack   Color    position
A       Red          1
A       Red          2
A       Red          3
A       blue         4
A       Blue         5
A       Red          6
A       Red          7
B       Red          1
C       blue         1
C       red          2
C       red          3
C       blue         4
```

The result i wont

```
Stack    Color      Quantity
A        Red        3
B        Red        1
C        Blue       1
```

- I have 3 sequential RED  starting from top in stack A
- I have 1 sequential RED  starting from top in stack B
- I have 1 sequential Blue starting from top in stack C

Comment: Please fix your formatting (using my edit as a sample of how to do it).

Comment: @Ven please stop mangling the question text and adding back grammatical errors. Nobody is going to mix up SQL Server with MySQL, you've already tagged that. You *won't* get any answer if the question is hard to read. It's hard enough to understand what you want right now.

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**

[DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be used to find the first "island" of colors per stack and aggregate it :

```
with islands as (
    select stack,color,position,
        position-dense_rank() over (partition by stack,color order by position) i
    from @table
)
select stack,color,count(*) as Count
from islands 
where i=0
group by stack,color
order by stack,color
```

This produces :

```
stack   color   Count
A       Red     3
B       Red     1
C       blue    1
```

**Explanation**

This is known as the [Islands problem](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9130/sql-server-window-functions-gaps-and-islands-problem/) - how to find "islands" of the same or consecutive values in a set of data.

The `Position` helps here as it changes behavior inside each `stack. What we need now is to find islands by color *inside* the stack. We can do this by calculating a DENSE_RANK by stack and color.

```
declare @table table (Stack varchar(2),Color varchar(10),Position int)

insert into @table(Stack   ,Color    ,position)
values
('A','Red'          ,1),
('A','Red'          ,2),
('A','Red'          ,3),
('A','blue'         ,4),
('A','Blue'         ,5),
('A','Red'          ,6),
('A','Red'          ,7),
('B','Red'          ,1),
('C','blue'         ,1),
('C','red'          ,2),
('C','red'          ,3),
('C','blue'         ,4)

select 
    stack,color,position,
    dense_rank() over (partition by stack,color order by position) as Rank
from @table
order by stack,position;
```

The results are :

```
stack   color   position    Rank
A       Red     1   1
A       Red     2   2
A       Red     3   3
A       blue    4   1
A       Blue    5   2
A       Red     6   4
A       Red     7   5
B       Red     1   1
C       blue    1   1
C       red     2   1
C       red     3   2
C       blue    4   2
```

The difference between the dense rank and the position is the same inside each color. We can use that to identify the islands :

```
select 
    stack,color,position,
    dense_rank() over (partition by stack,color order by position) as Rank,
    position-dense_rank() over (partition by stack,color order by position) as Island
from @table
order by stack,position
```

This produces :

```
stack   color   position    Rank    Island
A       Red     1           1       0
A       Red     2           2       0
A       Red     3           3       0
A       blue    4           1       3
A       Blue    5           2       3
A       Red     6           4       2
A       Red     7           5       2
B       Red     1           1       0
C       blue    1           1       0
C       red     2           1       1
C       red     3           2       1
C       blue    4           2       2
```

We can group by stack, color and island now to get the final result :

```
with x as (
    select stack,color,position,dense_rank() over (partition by stack,color order by position) r,
        position-dense_rank() over (partition by stack,color order by position) i
    from @table
)
select stack,color,count(*) as Count
from x 
where i=0
group by stack,color
order by stack,color
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have to be treated as a gaps-and-islands problem.  I think the simplest solution is:

```
select stack, first_color, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when color <> first_color then position end) over (partition by stack) as first_other_color_position
      from (select t.*, first_value(color) over (partition by stack order by position) as first_color
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where first_other_color_position is null or position < first_other_color_position
group by stack, first_color
order by stack;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99b4655880470935f65c272825cfd341) is a db<>fiddle.

The logic is simple:

- Get the first color for each stack.
- Get the position of the first rows for each that is not that color.
- Use that information to filter and aggregate the data.